# What does the C++ standard say about results of casting value of a type that lies outside the range of the target type?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

Recently I had to perform some data type conversions from `float` to 16 bit integer. Essentially my code reduces to the following

```
float f_val = 99999.0;
short int si_val = static_cast<short int>(f_val);

// si_val is now -32768
```

This input value was a problem and in my code I had neglected to check the limits of the float value so I can see my fault, but it made me wonder about the exact rules of the language when one has to do this kind of ungainly cast. I was slightly surprised to find that value of the cast was -32768. Furthermore, this is the value I get whenever the value of the float exceeds the limits of a 16 bit integer. I have googled this but found a surprising lack of detailed info about it. The best I could find was the following from cplusplus.com

> Converting to int from some smaller integer type, or to double from
>   float is known as promotion, and is guaranteed to produce the exact
>   same value in the destination type. Other conversions between
>   arithmetic types may not always be able to represent the same value
>   exactly:
>
> ```
> If the conversion is from a floating-point type to an integer type, the value 
> is truncated (the decimal part is removed).
> The conversions from/to bool consider false equivalent to zero (for numeric 
> types) and to null pointer (for pointer types); and true equivalent to all 
> other values.
> Otherwise, when the destination type cannot represent the value, the conversion 
> is valid between numerical types, but the value is
> implementation-specific (and may not be portable).
> ```

This suggestion that the results are implementation defined does not surprise me, but I have heard that cplusplus.com is not always reliable.

Finally, when performing the same cast from a 32 bit integer to 16 bit integer (again with a value outisde of 16 bit range) I saw results clearly indicating integer overflow. Although I was not surprised by this it has added to my confusion due to the inconsistency with the cast from `float` type.

I have no access to the C++ standard, but a lot of C++ people here do so I was wondering what the standard says on this issue? Just for completeness, I am using g++ version 4.6.3.

Comment: Narrowing conversions where you lose information have implementation-defined semantics. Your compiler has to document what it does in the case of implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: Asking for a standard quote, and mentioning your compiler? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to question what you've read. The conversion has no defined behaviour, which contradicts what you quoted in your question.

> **4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]**
>
> 1 A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
>   that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type. [ *Note:* If the destination type is `bool`, see 4.12. -- *end note* ]

One potentially useful permitted result that you might get is a crash.

Comment: Thankyou sir, a quote from the standard was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mathematician1975 If this answers your question, you should accept it.

Comment: @Casey It is ok - I know how things work here. It is not a race :)

Comment: @mathematician1975 Bah, I didn't notice your 10k rep. So used to new posters that forget to accept answers, I just assumed. "Unanswered" questions trigger my OCD.